# Swift 5.9: Parameter Packs getting Pack reference 'each V' can only appear in pack expansion

Tags: ios, swift, parameter-pack

Hi Im trying to use the new variadic generic feature of swift 5.9.

So I have a code that Im trying to refactor it:

```
func resolve<T>() -> T {
// Resolve method
}
    func autoResolve<T>(_ initializer: () -> T) -> T { initializer() }
    func autoResolve<T, A>(_ initializer: (A) -> T) -> T { initializer(resolve()) }
    func autoResolve<T, A, B>(_ initializer: (A, B) -> T) -> T { initializer(resolve(), resolve()) }
    func autoResolve<T, A, B, C>(_ initializer: (A, B, C) -> T) -> T { initializer(resolve(), resolve(), resolve()) }
    func autoResolve<T, A, B, C, D>(_ initializer: (A, B, C, D) -> T) -> T { initializer(resolve(), resolve(), resolve(), resolve()) }
    func autoResolve<T, A, B, C, D, E>(_ initializer: (A, B, C, D, E) -> T) -> T { initializer(resolve(), resolve(), resolve(), resolve(), resolve()) }
```

To

```
func autoResolve<T, each V>(_ initializer: (repeat each V) -> T) -> T { initializer(repeat each resolve()) }
```

But Im getting this error `Pack reference 'each V' can only appear in pack expansion`

Where is the problem?

Comment: It looks like you got the parentheses wrong, try `(_ initializer: repeat (each V) -> T) -> T`

Comment: Hmmm down work I get `Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code compiles and works. The secret here is that you need to give type evidence. The packed generic type `A` *must* be mentioned somewhere in the `repeat` expression. If you don't do that, it's simply not going to work. But if you experiment a bit you'll find it's quite flexible.

```
protocol Resolver {
  func resolve<T>() -> T
}

func auto<T, each A>(_ initializer: @escaping (repeat each A) -> T) -> (any Resolver) -> T {
  return { r in
    initializer(repeat r.resolve() as (each A))
  }
}

struct Foo {
  let x: Int
  let y: Int
}

let fooResolver = auto(Foo.init)
```

This is the pattern that I [used](https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/blob/b2e07b67c155fe6c4e2c75f6ed12dea533e2b27f/Sources/Guise/Registrar/Auto.swift#L20-L26) in [my own DI framework](https://github.com/prosumma/Guise) to replace the many overloads I have for `auto`.